# Remove comma using awk command with multiple record

Tags: shell, awk

Let says i've record like this. 
Input

```
1,1,1,1.213,1,1,1.23
2,2,2,2.345,2,2,2.33
3,3,3,3.456,3,3,3.44
```

I want to be like this

Output

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1.23
2,2,2,2,2,2,2.33
3,3,3,3,3,3,3.44
```

How to remove the comma only on column number 4th ?, i don't want to remove comma on last column

Comment: What should your output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1,$2,$3,int($4),$5,$6,$7}'
```

The `int()` is what you are looking for I guess.

Example:

> $ `cat test`

```
1,1,1,1.213,1,1,1.23
2,2,2,2.345,2,2,2.33
3,3,3,3.456,3,3,3.44
```

> $ `awk -F"," '{print $1,$2,$3,int($4),$5,$6,$7}' test`

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1.23
2 2 2 2 2 2 2.33
3 3 3 3 3 3 3.44
```

Edit (Good suggestion from [ccf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741681/ccf)):

You could use this instead of the long version of `awk` command above.

```
$ awk -F',' '{$4=int($4); print}'
1,1,1,1.213,1,1,1.23
1 1 1 1 1 1 1.23
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can accept the answer by clicking the big check mark beside the answer. @AmirRachman

Comment: To make it even simpler: awk -F',' '{$4=int($4); print}' test

Comment: @ccf thanks for the suggestion, I have edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

If temp.txt has the input, then

```
$ cat temp.txt | sed 's/\.[0-9]\+//1'
1,1,1,1,1,1,1.23
2,2,2,2,2,2,2.33
3,3,3,3,3,3,3.44
```

1 at the end means, only replace the first match.

Comment: You don't need the `1` though - that's the default behavior. Unlike the awk solution, this one will fail if the 4th column contains an integer and the last column doesn't.